# MQTT connection creation failed

Tags: connection, mqtt

```
software.amazon.awssdk.crt.CrtRuntimeException: 
aws_tls_ctx_options_init_client_mtls_from_path failed (aws_last_error: AWS_ERROR_FILE_INVALID_PATH(44), Invalid file path.) AWS_ERROR_FILE_INVALID_PATH(44)
```

Find Below Code..

```
// When run normally, we want to exit nicely even if something goes wrong
// When run from CI, we want to let an exception escape which in turn causes the
// exec:java task to return a non-zero exit code

static String ciPropValue = System.getProperty("aws.crt.ci");
static boolean isCI = ciPropValue != null && Boolean.valueOf(ciPropValue);
static Properties prop = null;
static InputStream input = null;
static String fileName = null;
static OutputStream output = null;
static String topic = "test/topic";
static String message = "Your Account will be credited by 100 Rupees!";
static int messagesToPublish = 10;

static CommandLineUtils cmdUtils;

static void onRejectedError(RejectedError error) {
    System.out.println("Request rejected: " + error.code.toString() + ": " + error.message);
}

/*
 * When called during a CI run, throw an exception that will escape and fail the
 * exec:java task When called otherwise, print what went wrong (if anything) and
 * just continue (return from main)
 */
static void onApplicationFailure(Throwable cause) {
    if (isCI) {
        throw new RuntimeException("BasicPubSub execution failure", cause);
    } else if (cause != null) {
        System.out.println("Exception encountered: " + cause.toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Property Reader: " + propertyReader("certificates.properties"));
    prop.getProperty("ca_file");
    System.out.println("key : " + prop.getProperty("key"));
    System.out.println("crt : " + prop.getProperty("cert"));

    cmdUtils = new CommandLineUtils();
    cmdUtils.registerProgramName("PubSub");
    cmdUtils.addCommonMQTTCommands();
    cmdUtils.addCommonTopicMessageCommands();
    cmdUtils.registerCommand("ca_file", prop.getProperty("ca_file"), "Path to your file in PEM format.");
    cmdUtils.registerCommand("key", prop.getProperty("key"), "Path to your key in PEM format.");
    cmdUtils.registerCommand("cert", prop.getProperty("cert"), "Path to your client certificate in PEM format.");
    cmdUtils.registerCommand("client_id", "BoM_QRCode_Sample_1", "Client id to use (optional, default='test-*').");
    cmdUtils.registerCommand("port", "8883", "Port to connect to on the endpoint (optional, default='8883').");
    cmdUtils.registerCommand("count", "10", "Number of messages to publish (optional, default='10').");
    cmdUtils.sendArguments(args);

    topic = cmdUtils.getCommandOrDefault("topic", topic);
    message = cmdUtils.getCommandOrDefault("message", message);
    messagesToPublish = Integer.parseInt(cmdUtils.getCommandOrDefault("count", String.valueOf(messagesToPublish)));

    MqttClientConnectionEvents callbacks = new MqttClientConnectionEvents() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionInterrupted(int errorCode) {
            if (errorCode != 0) {
                System.out.println("Connection interrupted: " + errorCode + ": " + CRT.awsErrorString(errorCode));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionResumed(boolean sessionPresent) {
            System.out.println("Connection resumed: " + (sessionPresent ? "existing session" : "clean session"));
        }
    };

    try {
        System.out.println("1");
        MqttClientConnection connection = cmdUtils.buildMQTTConnection(callbacks);

        if (connection == null) {
            onApplicationFailure(new RuntimeException("MQTT connection creation failed!"));
        }

        CompletableFuture<Boolean> connected = connection.connect();
        System.out.println("2");
        try {
            boolean sessionPresent = connected.get();
            System.out.println("Connected to " + (!sessionPresent ? "new" : "existing") + " session!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occurred during connect", ex);
        }

        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(messagesToPublish);

        CompletableFuture<Integer> subscribed = connection.subscribe(topic, QualityOfService.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
                (message) -> {
                    String payload = new String(message.getPayload(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + payload);
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                });

        subscribed.get();

        int count = 0;
        while (count++ < messagesToPublish) {
            CompletableFuture<Integer> published = connection
                    .publish(new MqttMessage(topic, message.getBytes(), QualityOfService.AT_LEAST_ONCE, false));
            published.get();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        countDownLatch.await();

        CompletableFuture<Void> disconnected = connection.disconnect();
        disconnected.get();
    } catch (CrtRuntimeException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        onApplicationFailure(ex);
    }

    CrtResource.waitForNoResources();
    System.out.println("Complete!");
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the full output. So we can see what file paths you have provided as that appears to be what it's complaining about.